# Oracle report (.rdf) reader

Tags: oraclereports

How can I read a Oracle reports .rdf? Is installing the Oracle Report Builder the only option, if so can someone share a link for it.

I need to read a .rdf file to see its content. The file is a Oracle report which gets the data from DB and creates a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a RDF file in any text editor. It'll be *awful*, but it is searchable so - if you're interested in its query, just search for SELECT and you'll get it.

Otherwise, if you really need to see the layout etc., Reports Builder installation is the only option, as far as I can tell.